# C# Inheritance Prevent Base Class Method Call Derived Class method

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base and a derived class as below:

```
//base class
public class BST
{
    public virtual void Find();
    public virtual void Insert()
    {
        Find();
    }
}


// derived class
public class splayTree:BST
{
    public override void Find()
    {
       base.Find();
       ...
    }
    public override void Insert()
    {
       base.Insert();
       .....
    }
}
```

After I created a splayTree object   splayTree，

- I call `splayTree.Insert();`
- `Insert()` calls `base.Insert()`
- `base.Insert()` calls `Find()` of the derived class.

How can I let `base.Insert()` call `Find()` of base class?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class has defined Find as Virtual, which is a signal that the child class may override it and if so, the base class will use that override.

If you want to call the base Find in your child class, just do not implement Find.

If you want to define a method called Find in your child class, that is not virtually connected to base.Find, use the new keyword instead of the override keyword.

Answer (score 0):

By not overriding the Find method:

```
//base class
public class BST
{
    public virtual void Find();
    public virtual void Insert()
    {
        Find();
    }
}


// derived class
public class splayTree:BST
{
    public void Find()
    {
       base.Find();
       ...
    }
    public override void Insert()
    {
       base.Insert();
       .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the base class' Find() method but still retain flexibility of having Find() be a virtual method with derived implementations, break out the logic of the base.Find() method into a private method you can call explicitly from the base class:

```
//base class
public class BST
{
    private void _Find()
    {
        // base.Find() implementation here
    }

    public virtual void Find()
    {
        _Find();
    }

    public virtual void Insert()
    {
        _Find();
    }
}


// derived class
public class splayTree:BST
{
    public override void Find()
    {
       base.Find();
       ...
    }
    public override void Insert()
    {
       base.Insert();
       .....
    }
}
```